# url-rewriting omitting directory from url?

Tags: url-rewriting, umbraco, umbraco7

Is it possible to remove a directory from URL? for example for the below urls:

```
http://localhost:50656/umbraco/Surface/HealthInsurance/Application?Pid=26665&Lid=73&Spid=23

http://localhost:50656/umbraco/Surface/HealthInsurance/Results/73
```

there need to remove `umbraco/Surface/` and make it

```
http://localhost:50656/HealthInsurance/Application?Pid=26665&Lid=73&Spid=23

    http://localhost:50656/HealthInsurance/Results/73
```

Please guide what will be regular expression for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the web server section of your web config you can add the following.  It will match the url .*, which is everything and will map it to /umbraco/Surface/{R:0}.  The R:0 is the entire captured response.  Make sure you have the module installed.  Here is a tutorial on how to check if you have your rewrite set and you can test it. http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/testing-rewrite-rule-patterns

```
<system.webServer>  
    <rewrite>
        <globalRules>
            <rule name="MapUmbarco">
                <match url=".*" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/umbraco/Surface/{R:0}" />
            </rule>
        </globalRules>
    </rewrite>

</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Thanks @John, can I do it using urlrewriting library as well ? I can use IIS since I don't have access. Please guide

Comment: @user576510 if you are in a shared hosting env, I would check with the hosting provider and see if the module is installed.  I know that godaddy has it installed by default in their shared hosting solutions.  If so you should be able to add the code to your web.config and it will just work.

Comment: @user576510 You can also roll your own url rewrite http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx see the section Building a URL Rewriting Engine